# fetch wordpress Listings Directory website data to Android using Json

Tags: php, json, database, wordpress

I have developed a wordpress directory listings website and a corresponding android app. My plan is to fetch the categories, listings and other data from wordpress using Json, I tried using the [Wordpress JSON REST API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) but It seems to me that this only exposes the core WordPress functionality (ie. posts, pages, users, etc.) and I can't see how to get this to execute custom queries on non-default tables.. I am unable to fetch the Categories and Listings which I created using the [WP Job Manager Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/).

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your wordpress setup plugins folder. Go to rest-api -> plugin.php.

1. Find this

   ```
   function _add_extra_api_post_type_arguments() {
   }
   ```

Add the following code before its closing tag and you'll have the api working on /v2/joblistings/

```
    if ( isset( $wp_post_types['job_listing'] ) ) {
    $wp_post_types['job_listing']->show_in_rest = true;
    $wp_post_types['job_listing']->rest_base = 'joblistings';
    $wp_post_types['job_listing']->rest_controller_class =      'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
    }
```

2. Find this
       function _add_extra_api_taxonomy_arguments() {
       }

Add the following code before its closing tag and you'll have the api working on /v2/joblistingcategorys/

```
    //Taxonomy for listings
    if ( isset( $wp_taxonomies['job_listing_category'] ) ) {
    $wp_taxonomies['job_listing_category']->show_in_rest = true;
    $wp_taxonomies['job_listing_category']->rest_base =    'joblistingcategorys';
    $wp_taxonomies['job_listing_category']->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller';
    }
```

Source is http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/

Adding rest API support to existing content types.